# The relationship could not be changed .. the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to update an entity of type `MamConfiguration_V1`

which exsit already in the DB

It has few reference members (among them `MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1`)

```
  private void UpdateEfItem(MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromDb, MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromUi)
    {
        itemFromDb.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

        itemFromDb.Description = itemFromUi.Description;

        itemFromDb.StatusId = itemFromUi.StatusId;

        itemFromDb.Name = itemFromUi.Name;

        itemFromDb.NumericTraffic = itemFromUi.NumericTraffic;

        itemFromDb.PercentageTraffic = itemFromUi.PercentageTraffic;

        itemFromDb.Type = itemFromUi.NumericTraffic;


        itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Clear();



        for (int i = 0; i < itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Count; i++)
        {
            var elementToAdd = itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ElementAt(i);

            elementToAdd.Browser = mMaMDBEntities.Browsers.Single(browserItem => browserItem.BrowserID == elementToAdd.BrowserID);

            elementToAdd.MamConfiguration_V1 = itemFromDb;

            itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Add(elementToAdd);
        }
```

}

I get the following DB runtime error:

The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

But that's weird. All the references are not null:

[image]

[image]

**Upadte 2:**

I have tried this code:

```
        try
        {
            item.ThrowIfNull("item");

            var itemFromDB = GetById(item.ConfigurationId);

            if (itemFromDB != null)
            {
                UpdateEfItem(itemFromDB, item);

                //mMaMDBEntities.MamConfiguration_V1.Detach(itemFromDB);

                //mMaMDBEntities.MamConfiguration_V1.Attach(item);

                //mMaMDBEntities.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(item, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

                //mMaMDBEntities.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(itemFromDB, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);


                mMaMDBEntities.SaveChanges();

                return item;
            }
```

}

```
        private void UpdateEfItem(MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromDb, MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromUi)
        {
            itemFromDb.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            itemFromDb.Description = itemFromUi.Description;
            itemFromDb.StatusId = itemFromUi.StatusId;
            itemFromDb.Name = itemFromUi.Name;
            itemFromDb.NumericTraffic = itemFromUi.NumericTraffic;
            itemFromDb.PercentageTraffic = itemFromUi.PercentageTraffic;
            itemFromDb.Type = itemFromUi.NumericTraffic;

            foreach (var item in itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ToList())
            {
                if (itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.All(b => b.BrowserVersionId != item.BrowserVersionId))
                {
                    mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.DeleteObject(item);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Count; i++)
            {
                var element = itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ElementAt(i);
                var item = itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BrowserVersionId == element.BrowserVersionId);
                if (item != null)
                {
                    // copy properties from element to item
                }
                else
                {
                    element.Browser = mMaMDBEntities.Browsers.Single(browserItem =>
                        browserItem.BrowserID == element.BrowserID);

                    element.MamConfiguration_V1 = itemFromDb;

                    //have also tried: element.MamConfiguration_V1 = null;

                    //element.MamConfiguration_V1Reference = null;

                    itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Add(element);
                }
            }
        }
```

and go this error:

> {"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_MamConfigurations_V1'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MamConfiguration_V1'. The
>   duplicate key value is (elad_14Apr_1315).\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line...

```
itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Clear();
```

...will not only clear the collection but also set the reference from the individual items in the collection to the parent `itemFromDb` to `null`. That's a modification of those items and EF will try to save them to the database. It fails because (probably) the reference is required and cannot be `null`.

You must take a different approach, that is updating the items in the collection one by one. You must take into account that items could have been deleted in the UI, that they could have been modified and that new items could have been added. It would look similar to this:

```
private void UpdateEfItem(MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromDb,
    MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromUi)
{
    itemFromDb.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    itemFromDb.Description = itemFromUi.Description;
    itemFromDb.StatusId = itemFromUi.StatusId;
    itemFromDb.Name = itemFromUi.Name;
    itemFromDb.NumericTraffic = itemFromUi.NumericTraffic;
    itemFromDb.PercentageTraffic = itemFromUi.PercentageTraffic;
    itemFromDb.Type = itemFromUi.NumericTraffic;

    foreach (var item in itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ToList())
    {
        if (!itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Any(b =>
            b.BrowserID == item.BrowserID)
        {
            mMaMDBEntities.Browsers.DeleteObject(item);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Count; i++)
    {
        var element = itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ElementAt(i);
        var item = itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1
            .SingleOrDefault(b => b.BrowserID == element.BrowserID);
        if (item != null)
        {
            // copy properties from element to item
        }
        else
        {
            element.Browser = mMaMDBEntities.Browsers.Single(browserItem =>
                browserItem.BrowserID == element.BrowserID);

            itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Add(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error on `mMaMDBEntities.SaveChanges();` : {"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_MamConfigurations_V1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MamConfiguration_V1'. The duplicate key value is (elad_14Apr_1315).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: @EladBenda: Do the items in the `itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V` collection have a reference to a `MamConfigurations_V1`? That would be a problem because EF will try to insert them together with the new items.

Comment: Yes. In EF reference navigations are bi-directionals. And all my new items in `itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V` refere to existing `MamConfigurations_V1`. What should I do?

Comment: @EladBenda: Try to set the references to either `null` or to `itemFromDb` directly after the `var element = ...` line.

Comment: But I did that already: `elementToAdd.MamConfiguration_V1 = itemFromDb;`

Comment: @EladBenda: Also in my example code? I had removed the line, did you add that again?

Comment: Yes: `                    else
                    {
                        element.Browser = mMaMDBEntities.Browsers.Single(browserItem =>
                            browserItem.BrowserID == element.BrowserID);

                        element.MamConfiguration_V1 = null;

                        element.MamConfiguration_V1Reference = null;

                        itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Add(element);
                    }`

Comment: @EladBenda: Do you also pass the `if` case and/or the `DeleteObject` loop in your test case or only the `else` case?

Comment: In my scenario I pass the `else` case. I add BrowserRefernce that didn't exist in the DB

Comment: @EladBenda: And you load the `itemFromDb`, then call `UpdateEfItem`, then call `SaveChanges`, all with the same context instance, right? And no call of `AddObject`?

Comment: exactly. This is the exact flow

Comment: @EladBenda: Sorry, but I am unable to see the problem without debugging.  Updating detached objects graphs with EF is generally hard, but it is especially hard with those old-fashioned entities derived from `EntityObject`. I believe that this duplicate `MamConfiguration_V1` entity somehow comes from the object graph from UI, you must find out where it gets attached to the context, either directly or through another attached object that is referencing it.

Comment: How would you repply to this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913771/insert-record-in-child-table-when-parent-record-already-exists-using-entity-fram

Comment: when is is derived from `EntityObject` and when from `DBcontext`?

Comment: I get `MamConfiguration_V1` at the smae context I save the changes. It's attached to the same context. The flow: get MamConfiguration_V1  with Id that I got in the UI (edit mode) --> assign all values to it from the UI --> override\add\delete reference members (navigation) `MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1`. Did that add info?

Comment: @EladBenda: That question is another situation. You have loaded the `itemFromDb` from the database, it is already attached, so you don't to attach manually. You get `DbContext` from the Entity Framework NuGet package. `EntityObject` is default for EF <= 4.0.

Comment: `itemFromDb from the database, it is already attached, so you don't to attach manually`. But I haven't. you can see my code

Comment: I have written all the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144759/ef-adding-a-new-navigation-property-to-an-exsiting-in-the-db-entity-under-the?noredirect=1#comment23066064_16144759