# Entity Framework 6 Model First: how to add inherited entity when base entity already exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6, ef-model-first

Using Entity Framework 6 Model First.

Two entities in the project, `Person` and `Worker`

`Person` is the base class of `Worker`

I'm able to create brand new `Worker` which also create new `Person`

But when a `Person` entity already exist in database, how would I extend it, and add to `Worker`?

Comment: Isn' this duplicate? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913771/insert-record-in-child-table-when-parent-record-already-exists-using-entity-fram)

Comment: looks like it, i might have used wrong keyword in the search, will try the solution. Thanks

Comment: @Farhad, sorry I think it's not, the provided solution `Parent` and `Child` were 1 to Many. But it's `inherited` entity in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Because Person is already created there is really now way to make it a Worker anymore. So in this case if you want to keep using the inheritance relationship you have no other option than to remove the existing person and recreate it as a worker.
Another option is to let go of the inheritance relationship because in that case it is just a matter of adding a record in the worker table.

This problem is also described in Programming Entity Framework by Julia Lerman where she identifies this as one of the downsides of using inheritance in EF.